# Custom post type archive page pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, archives, custom-post-type-archives, paginate-links

I have set up an archive page for my custom post type `reference`, where I use a query to get all posts of type `reference`. This works, but when I try to paginate the result, it doesn't work. Right now, it doesn't even print out the pagination links.

EDIT: This was earlier used on a regular page, but I changed it to an archive page. That's when the pagination broke.

Here is the source code;

Custom post type `reference` (plugin)

```
<?php
   /*
   comments here removed 
   */
?>
<?php

/* Custom post types */
function create_references_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => __( 'References', 'kasparabi' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'Reference', 'kasparabi' ),
        'add_new'            => __( 'Add New', 'kasparabi' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add new reference', 'kasparabi' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit reference', 'kasparabi' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New reference', 'kasparabi' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All references', 'kasparabi' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View reference', 'kasparabi' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search references', 'kasparabi' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No references found', 'kasparabi' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No references found in the Trash', 'kasparabi' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => __('References', 'kasparabi')
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => __('All the references', 'kasparabi'),
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
        'has_archive'   => __('references', 'kasparabi')/*,
        'rewrite'       => array('slug' => __('references', 'kasparabi'))*/
    );
    register_post_type( 'reference', $args );   
}
add_action('init', 'create_references_post_type');

function add_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'reference' ) );
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_post_type_to_query' );

?>
```

The way I query for the posts:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'reference', 
                        'posts_per_page' => 9,
                        'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 
                    ));
```

How I print out the pagination links:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <?php previous_posts_link(__('&larr; newer', 'kasparabi')); ?>

    <?php if ($loop->max_num_pages > $paged) :
        next_posts_link(__('older &rarr;', 'kasparabi'), $posts_per_page);
    endif; ?>
</div>
```

And as a bonus question; is there another way to get the posts than creating a new query every time?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
```

And next_posts_link/previous_posts_links has these arguments:

```
 next_posts_link( $label , $max_pages );
```

*$label* is not a string in your code but a kind of an array?

I am not so familiar with these "magical PHP functions", but what do you suppose these "__" to do? As far as I am informed, one should not use these.

Comment: The 1 seems to have dissapeared in the copy-paste, you are right about that.
The `next_posts_link`/`previous_posts_link` funtions get in a string; `&larr;` and `&rarr;` are special characters for a left and a right arrow. I know that works.
The `__()` function, as far as I know, marks text for translation, similarly to e.g. `_e()`. You would then later use a tool to translate all the marked strings.

Comment: I don't know if this `__()` function is accepted by WordPress. Does it work for you if you only use one string like `next_posts_link('older &rarr;', $posts_per_page);` or does this also not work?

Comment: `__()` is refered to here -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Localization_Technology

`__()` basically returns a string, and before I made it an archive page, this worked. The problem I have is probably related to me using this as an archive now, rather than a normal page.

Answer (score 0):

You register your post type with the name of `reference` in this case you can use the built in [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png) to get the correct loop. Create a file in the root of your theme folder with the name `archive-reference.php`.

In this file you don't have to query the references because it will be automatic by WordPress. The only thing that you have to write in this file is a simple logic:

```
<?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <?php _e( 'Sorry, no results were found.', 'kasparabi' ); ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <article <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

    <div class="entry-summary"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('Read More', 'kasparabi'); ?></a>
  </article>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
  <nav class="post-nav">
    <ul class="pager">
      <li class="previous"><?php next_posts_link(__('Older', 'kasparabi')); ?></li>
      <li class="next"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer', 'kasparabi')); ?></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will list your references with their title and excerpt.

Don't forget to allow rewrite in your post type declaration:

```
  $rewrite = array(
    'slug'                  => 'references',
    'with_front'            => false,
    'pages'                 => true,
    'feeds'                 => true,
  );

  ...

  'rewrite' => $rewrite,
```

If you want to query your references on a page, you always have to build a custom query. This answer could help you how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20905538/2043492

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

/*this one your query*/
global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'reference', 
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 
));

/*pagination code here with update max pages*/            

$GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
the_posts_pagination(array(
    'mid_size' => 1,
    'prev_text' => __('Previous page', 'patelextensions'),
    'next_text' => __('Next page', 'patelextensions'),
    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __('Page', 'patelextensions') . ' </span>',
));
```